# How can I filter a Sharepoint 2007 libarry list based on current user login?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I would like to know how I can filter a SharePoint library list based on current user login.

Suppose I have created the followings:
1) A SharePoint form library containing bunch of uploaded InfoPath form data.
2) The InfoPath form template contains a promoted text field called "TargetUser" to store user domain login (ex: DOMAIN\JOE) and every InfoPath form file in the library has a valid domain name stored in the "TargetUser" field.

I have created a custom view for the form library and would like to filter this view so only items whose "TargetUser" field matches current user's login ID are displayed.

I went to Edit View page to customize the view and tried to use the [Me] function but I got a "Filter value is not a valid text string" message instead when clicking OK.  Apparently [Me] returns a Person/Group data type and the filter cannot compare its value to that of "TargetUser".

I tried using other text functions (ex: TEXT([Me],"") hoping to extract default string value from [Me].  The filter accepted the parameter without any error but the resulting fitlered list does not display any items at all.

I have googled this subject but I have not found any solution.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help me to create a functional filtered list.
And FYI, my SharePoint 2007 installation is just WSS 3.0 + Form Server.  I do not have MOSS 2007 (so no MOSS 2007 web parts or web services).

Thank you.

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason your TargetUser field is a text field instead of a People or Group field? 
The [Me] identifier can be used to filter list items based on a People or Group column, but not on text fields.

Comment: I understand that [Me] will work with People/Group type but when the Infopath form tempate was developed, user login was stored in a text field.  Since the forms have been in used for over two years, it is too late to go back and change the template.

Comment: FYI, my site is currently using DataView web part to display and filter the form library list.  In DataView web part, we are able to use server variable "LOGON_USER" (a string value) in the filter.  I suppose that was the reason the form template was originally designed to store user login in a text field.  But now We would like to use the ListView web part instead is because it has better performance when displaying large number of items and also it allows users to do easier sorting and mutiple-filters.  DataView web part only allows user filter at a time and it is kind of awkward to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well.  It looks like no one here has the answer.
Nevertheless, another user on Technet forum has a very good solution.
See this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/13784bb8-5ec3-4cd0-b995-79b44d9b1438) for more information